# Print html content in Ionic2 page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic2

I have a **ionic2** page and i want to **print HTML** inside the ion-item:
Here is the ionic2 page:

```
@Page({
    templateUrl: './html-page.html',
})
export class Demo{

    htmlString:string = "Hello<br/><br/>Html"

    constructor() {
    }
}
```

and here is the corresponding template:

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card>
        {{htmlString}}
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

And **now** `Hello<br/><br/>Html` is output. **but i want** that

Hello

Html

will be output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Please try it this way.

```
<ion-content>
<ion-card>
<div [innerHTML] = "'<p>' + htmlString + '</p>'"></div>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may also use iframe if you want to display render your html text - big one too.

some.html

```
Hello<br/><br/>Html
```

then:-

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card>
        <iframe src="some.html"></iframe>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```